# Serve a HTML File with NodeJS

Tags: node.js, backbone.js, web

I have developed a **backbone.js page** where **data was being scrapped Through an API call**.
I was  **running the public files via Apache directly**.
But i want to **run it through node.js**

I tried using

```
var sys = require('sys'),
    http = require('http'),
    fs = require('fs'),
    index;

fs.readFile('./index.html', function (err, data) {
    if (err) {
        throw err;
    }
    index = data;
});

http.createServer(function(request, response) {
    response.writeHeader(200, {"Content-Type": "text/html"});
    response.write(index);
    response.end();   
}).listen(8000);
```

but it did not work as when i open it a blank html page opens up.Although the title of the page change.
As the title of the page is changing but it is unable to process body part of the file.
*The code of html page is*

```
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <title>Movie db</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/screen.css" />
    </head>
    <body>
    <div id="moviedb"></div>
    <script id="moviedbTemplate" type="text/template">
    <dl><h4>
    <dt>Score:</dt><dd><%= score %></dd>
    <dt>Popularity:</dt><dd><%= popularity %></dd>
<dt>Translated:</dt><dd><%= translated %></dd>
<dt>Adult:</dt><dd><%= adult%></dd>
<dt>Language:</dt><dd><%= language %></dd>
<dt>Original_Name:</dt><dd><%= original_name %></dd>
<dt>Name:</dt><dd><a href=":<%= name %>"><%= name %></a></dd>
<dt>Alternative_name:</dt><dd><%= alternative_name %></dd>
<dt>Movie_type:</dt><dd><%= movie_type %></dd>
<dt>imdb_id:</dt><dd><%= imdb_id %></dd>
<dt>Votes:</dt><dd><%= votes %></dd>
<dt>Rating:</dt><dd><%= rating %></dd>
<dt>Runtime:</dt><dd><%= runtime %></dd>
<dt>Certification:</dt><dd><%= certification %></dd>
<dt>Overview:</dt><dd><%= overview %></dd>
<dt>Released:</dt><dd><%= released %></dd></h4>    
    </dl>
    <hr>
    </script>
    <script src="js/index.js"></script>
    <script src="js/jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/json2.js"></script>
    <script src="js/underscore-min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/backbone-min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/app.js"></script>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: fs.readFile is async, how do you know you are not asking for the file before it is available?

Comment: @Radek It is fine. He reads file before initializing the server ( it happens only once during server's lifetime ). It sounds impossible to be fast enough to refresh the page before the file is read. :)

Comment: But the question is: what do you mean by `it did not work`? Any errors?

Comment: honestly, i don't.
can you suggest how to know ?

Comment: there were no errors as it just shows a blank html page.

Comment: @AbhishekDwivedi Then it means that you've passed a blank (or incorrect) HTML. :) I've just tested your code and it works fine!

Comment: The html page works correctly and it also shows the scrapped data.it does not work correctly only while opening through above code.and yes i have also tested the code it works fine otherwise. can you point out the possible error /changes that need to be done.

Comment: @AbhishekDwivedi Perhaps something's wrong when server tries to read file? Using `throw err` inside `fs.readFile` doesn't do much, because it happens in separate "thread" anyway (`fs.readFile` is asynchronous). Instead of throwing an error put `console.log(err)` and `console.log(index)` inside `fs.readFile`. You will know whether NodeJS read the file or not. If it does read it, then there's nothing I (or anybody else) can do for you. Good luck!